# Handle back button event not working on device

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

In my react native app, I'm trying to prevent the user from going back on the login screen if he is on the main screen (TabNavigator).

I searched and found a solution working well on the emulator:

```
componentDidMount()
{
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressed);
}

componentWillUnMount()
{
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressed);
}

onBackButtonPressed = () => true;
```

...but unfortunately, there is no way to get it working on a real device (Android Oreo).

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: Most probable cause is that since react-navigation registers a BackHandler too, your listener can't even get the event as that event is handled already. One possible way to solve it should be to set it up before you create your navigators, could you try it?

Comment: The thing is that all my screens are defined in a StackNavigator, so I guess I can't do it this way. I will just set the TabNavigator as the main screen and if the user is not logged in, I display the LoginScreen. Thanks for your answer